# Eigen unaligned assert

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, eigen

I'm using Eigen 3.1.2 and I am able to build a 64-bit target of my application without any problems. When I build a 32-bit target, I got a lot of "unaligned" asserts. So I followed the [workaround](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__Alignement.html) by defining EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW in all my classes, and using Eigen::aligned_allocator for all the STL containers. This seems to have taken care of all the asserts. However, in debug mode, I crash at a certain point. Here is where it crashes:

m_container.resize(N)

This is a resize operation on m_container which is a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<pFOO> > >` (a 3D array of pFOO), where pFOO is a pointer to a FOO object. I'm defining the pointer using a `pFOO = std::shared_ptr<FOO>`. Also, class FOO has a few Eigen members and I've defined a public EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW in the class. Will `std::shared_ptr<FOO>` use the aligned allocator by default? Any reason why it would crash at the resize operation ? What else could I try ?

EDIT:
The workarounds suggested in the Eigen documentation state that for STL containers of classes containing Eigen members, I must use the Eigen::aligned_allocator as an additional parameter to the std::vector declaration. In my case, I have an std::vector of *pointers* to the class containing Eigen members. I am relying on the EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW to do the aligned allocation and am not using the Eigen::aligned_allocator in the std::vector declaration.

Comment: What line or subroutine of `resize(N)` causes the crash?

Comment: @japreiss The crash happens at std::_Allocate in the following lines: 
if (_Count == 0)
  ;
 else if (((size_t)(-1) / sizeof (_Ty) < _Count)
  || (_Ptr = ::operator new(_Count * sizeof (_Ty))) == 0)
  _Xbad_alloc(); // report no memory

Since it happens at operator new (), I'm guessing that it is related to Eigen using an aligned allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Eigen's documentation refers to using a `vector` of Eigen objects directly, not a vector of pointers to Eigen objects.  The `allocator` parameter won't get passed on to the `shared_ptr`s.  Since you must initialize the `shared_ptr` with a heap-allocated object yourself [1], the responsibility is on you to allocate with the proper alignment.

[1] http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: Is there any way, I could use the provided allocator http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1aligned__allocator.html for this purpose? How would I declare it? For example, std::vector<FOO, Eigen::aligned_allocator<FOO> > works for a vector of Eigen objects, how would I do it for a vector of FOO* ? How would I contruct my own allocator ?

Comment: You should be able to use the Eigen allocator via its [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) interface... but I don't speak from experience.

Comment: There are two issues here.. the alignment of the Eigen member inside FOO and the alignment of the vector of FOO*... Assuming the EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW takes care of overloading the new operator.. std::shared_ptr would call the new overloaded operator itself right ?

Comment: This is similar to the issue faced and addressed here --> http://www.pcl-users.org/Can-t-avoid-Eigen-alignment-problems-td2531193.html

The difference being that I do not call make_shared. How does resize do the reallocation ?

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassing to admit but the crashes in std::_Allocate were related to out of memory issues. I was fooled into thinking that they were related to alignment issues.